# Issues with importing data in date format from excel to oracle 10g?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

hello I am trying to import date formatted data from excel to oarcle 10g databse using SQL developer, earlier I had no idea, but after revising various questions in stackoverflow I came to know that it can be worked using SQL developer,Here is the process, I tried to import using right click on the table in sql developer selecting the column names followed by DATE format to be mentioned for the columns that have date, but I am not succeeded. Atlast I verified whether all the columns have success in their status, I have success for all the columns but after finish the error is "The date should be between 1 and last day of the month, Can anyone let me now how to fix it please ?

Answer (score 0):

sometimes it caused by the format from your excel file..make sure that your excel file has a right Date format. Like dd-mm-rr

You can try navicat software to import excel file into oracle

Comment: I did not work @blackrabbit .....Is there any other process to do..even In excel there is no format for dd-mm-rr. I tried to do using custom format, i think excel doesnt recognize dd-mm-rr